# which ms visio version supports windows xp sp2?

Tags: visio

where can i fing ms office visio 2010 trial version which is compatible with windows xp sp2?
could any body out there suggest me some alternate solution as visio 2010 supports all os versions except xp sp2.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio 2010 requires Service Pack 3 to run under Windows XP. From the [system requirements](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-office-2010-system-requirements-HA101810407.aspx#_Toc250543120):

> Windows XP (must have SP3) (32-bit),
>   Windows 7, Windows Vista with Service
>   Pack (SP) 1, Windows Server 2003 R2
>   with MSXML 6.0 (32-bit Office only),
>   Windows Server 2008, or later 32- or
>   64-bit OS.

The latest version of Visio that will run under Windows XP SP2 is Visio 2007. See [system requirements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829913):

> **Visio 2007**
>
> - Windows Vista
> - Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 (SP1) or later
> - Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) or later
>
> **Visio 2003**
>
> - Windows Vista
> - Microsoft Windows XP or later
> - Microsoft Windows 2000 Service Pack 3 (SP3) or later

I don't really understand why you can't just apply Service Pack 3 to Windows XP (it's a [free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5B33B5A8-5E76-401F-BE08-1E1555D4F3D4&displaylang=en)), but if this is not an option, then you'll have to purchase an older version of Visio that is compatible with your operating system. Stack Overflow is not in the business of providing software downloads.